# IWebHost: Graceful Shutdown isn't so Graceful

Tags: asp.net-core

How do I configure an `IWebHost` so that it will service all pending requests before actually shutting down?

I have library that will do the following:

1. Spin up an `IWebHost` that is listening for a connection.
2. Listen for the connection and "Process" it.
   2a.  If it successfully processes the request, it adds the result to a queue and redirects to a success page on another server.
   2b.  If it does not, it simply redirects to an error page on another server.
3. Another thread is waiting for an item to appear in the queue and when it does, it calls `StopAsync` on the IWebHost.

The problem that I am facing is that it that StopAsync seems to be immediately disposing of things before the request is complete.  Half the time Kestrel logs an error and a 500 error is shown because my actively running controller was disposed.

How do I keep that from happening?

Here is my error:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://127.0.0.1:52240/OAuth/Complete?code=ABCDEFG - - - 0 - - 5251.9983ms
```

Comment: What does it mean `Listen for the connection and "Process" it`? How can you process connection? Do you mean receiving and processing web request? Your question is unclear and it's hard to understand how it works. Please give more details so people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is the right behavior, during the shutdown, if one request will take 20 minutes, the server shouldn't wait 20 minutes and then do the dispose.

The right way is when you want to stop the method, you should build the logic by yourself to redirect all the request or write a middleware to show the server will restart in 5 minutes.

Then inside the stop method wait 5 minutes to let the request continue working 5 minutes then use this stopasync method to stop the whole application.